# Import 1000+ subnets in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an existing AWS infrastructure which has more than 1000 subnets. We are to start infrastructure automation using Terraform and use it against the existing infra for further infra deployments on top of the existing one.

Is there an easy method to import 1000+ subnets in such a way that after I import, it should understand the existing resources and then apply (add/delete) on top of the existing infra?

I did try terraformer (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/blob/master/docs/aws.md). However, when the statefile doesn't seem to recognise the same.

Comment: Hi, is this relevant? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import

Comment: It is, however, for 1000+ subnets forming a logic is getting challenging. I have been trying this approach.

Comment: Try `former2` tool on github.